# Execute a method once every transaction begins inside methods annotated with spring - @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I want to make a database call before every method within my Spring application annotated with ***@Transactional*** started executing transaction.

There are few requirements for this:

1. This database call has to be part of the actual transaction that is about to begin.
2. The database connection used for the Transaction has to be same to be used for this database call and should setup some database data before 'real' transaction begins.

Is there something that Spring supports to achieve this goal ? One way I am thinking is to write own Aspect cloning more or less all Transactional code as is. Other way is to write Aspect. Not sure if there are more ways.